# Set the id of a drop-down within a class

Tags: php, class

I am trying to use a class to generate a drop down for input fields. The drop down works and is populated, however I am trying to find documentation how to set the id  from the variable passed to the class. The reason is that the drop down should be used on various forms but at different positions, so I was hoping to set the id this way.

```
<?php
class ddUsers {
    public $dfID;
    
    function set_id($dfID) {
        $this->id = $dfID;
    }
    
    function getField() {
    // query code is here, standard select with mysqli //
?>
    <select class ="inline" id ='How to get the ID in here?' name = "UUID" value = "">
    <option> // query results via for loop go here // </option>
```

Calling the class works:

```
$field = new ddUsers();
$field->set_id(17);
$field->getField();
```

Comment: Do you just need to add a getter like `function getId() { return $this->id; }` and then call it like `id="<?= $field->getId(); ?>"`

Comment: That didn't quite work, but you got me trying some more and I arrived at the result with simply inserting <?php echo $this->id; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with simply `echo $this->id` as the `<select>` code is within the function:

```
    <select class ='inline' id ='<?php echo $this->id; ?>' name = 'UUID' value = ''>
<option>Please select a user:</option>"
```

And the result from "view source" is:

```
 <select class ='inline' id ='17' name = 'UUID' value = ''>
    <option>Please select a user:</option>"
<option value=2>Username1</option><option value=1>Username2</option></select>
```